# Changing the orientation of a UIViewController, affects the bounds of another UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uitableview, constraints

I have a UITableViewController, I can add cells to it from another UIViewController.

If the device is on the landscape mode, and I navigated to the UIViewController, and then navigated back to the UITableViewController, the bounds are fine.
Same thing if I'm on the portriat mode, if I navigated to the UIViewController, and navigated back to the UITableViewController, the bounds are fine.

The issue start showing if I'm on the UITableViewController on a specific orientation mode, and navigated to the UIViewController and changed the orientation there. When I navigate back to the UITableViewController, the bounds are totally messed up.

Meaning that the bounds of UITableViewController only get messed up when I change the orientation in the ViewController.

Here is a screenshots:

Portrait normal bounds on left:       Portrait messed bounds on right:
   [image]              [image]

landscape normal bounds on left:                      landscape messed bounds on right: 
[image] [image]

I have tried many things like:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {// tried viewWillLayoutSubviews() too
    self.tableView.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.tableView.updateConstraintsIfNeeded()
}
```

Please let me know if you need any extra info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it why it's happening, I'll keep the question for everyone might hit the same issue.

I'm using a custom transitioning for dismissing the UIViewController, UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning, and I'm not checking whether I'm on a landscape mode or portrait mode in the custom transitioning.

If you're facing the same issue, please, make sure you're reverting to bounds of the screen.